# What mistake am I doing in this code for selection sort?

Tags: sorting, selection-sort

```
var selectionSort = function(array) {
    var minIndex;
    for(var i = 0;i <array.length;i++){
        minIndex = indexOfMinimum(array,i);}
         swap(array,minIndex,i);
};
```

where `indexOfMinimum` is used to find the index of  min value for the subarray starting at index `i`. And `swap` is a popularly known function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem with curly braces, see `minIndex = indexOfMinimum(array,i);}`. So basically `swap(array,minIndex,i);` is executed only once, not in the loop body.
Your code with corrected style:

```
var selectionSort = function(array) {
    var minIndex;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        minIndex = indexOfMinimum(array,i);
    }
    swap(array,minIndex,i);
};
```

What you need:

```
var selectionSort = function(array) {
    var minIndex;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        minIndex = indexOfMinimum(array,i);
        swap(array,minIndex,i);
    }
};
```